# Why do the names for Slavic languages frequently end in ски (ski)?

Tags: vocabulary

Does "ски"(ski) mean something on it's own or is it just a coincidence? Russian is Русский, Bulgarian is Български, Serbian is Srpski, Polish is Polski etc. Ukrainian is Українська.

Comment: The same reason why Danish is "Dansk", Norwegian is "Norsk" and Swedish is "Svenska" in those respective languages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This suffix comes from Proto-Slavic **-ьskъ*, cognate with English "-ish", and is used in a similar way: to turn a noun into an adjective. For example, Russian герой *geroj* "hero" > геройский *gerojskij* "heroic", дети *deti* "child" > детский *detskij* "childish".

Рус-ский, thus, is an adjective from Русь: "Rus-ish". And similarly in other Slavic languages, though the exact form of the suffix varies.

Comment: This adjective would apply to whatever the word for "language" was, in context.

Answer (score 5):

Proto-Indo-European suffix -iskos, which means "Characteristic of, typical of, pertaining to", is inherited by Balto-Slavic, Germanic and Hellenic. The Proto-Balto-Slavic one is -iškas, while the Proto-Slavic one is -ьskъ.

Comment: The link to the article about the suffix: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/-iskos

Comment: These is also late Latin `-iscus` (now present in Ital. `-esco`, Rom. `-esc`, Fr. `-esque` etc) said to come from Proto-West Germanic *-isk, from Proto-Germanic *-iskaz, from Proto-Indo-European *-iskos (suffix), although its presence in Romanian may prove a rather common-Latin base.